# VBA Insert correlating array formula into cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an input page, where the user can determine the number of accounts they need and which will display on the overview page. There are six different types of account.  I have accomplished this using the Copy property. My code pastes each of the six types one at a time.

```
With Sheet4
    .Range("B9", .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Copy Sheet7.[A4]
End With
```

Next, for each row, I need to insert a specified formula for each account. I have accomplished this as so:

```
'then count sheet7 col a
qRow = wsA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'paste the formula
Dim q As Long
For q = 2 To qRow
    If wsA.Cells(q, 1).Value > 1000 Then
        wsA.Cells(q, 5).Value = "=sum(2+1)"
    End If
    Next q
```

So far, so good. My problem occurs at this juncture, because the following is the actual formula I need to insert, and it needs to be an ARRAY formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B!$D:$D,B!$E:$E,$A5,B!$B:$B,">="&E$2,B!$B:$B,"<"&F$2)*1,SUMIFS(B!$D:$D,B!$F:$F,$A5,B!$B:$B,">="&E$2,B!$B:$B,"<"&F$2)*-1)
```

I tried messing with the .formulaArray property, but I kept getting "Object Required"

Any thoughts?
I'm open to changing up my code, if anyone has a better idea on how to accomplish this. Thanks!

UPDATE 10FEB15

Error code is "mismatch" on the commented line:

```
If wsA.Cells(q, 1).Value > 1000 Then
        'wsA.Cells(q, 5).FormulaArray = "=SUM(SUMIFS(B!$D:$D,B!$E:$E,$A5,B!$B:$B," >= "&E$2,B!$B:$B," < "&F$2)*1,SUMIFS(B!$D:$D,B!$F:$F,$A5,B!$B:$B," >= "&E$2,B!$B:$B," < "&F$2)*-1)"   
    End If
```

SOLUTION:
In VBA we mask double quotes by repeating them.

```
Dim s As String
's = "He said: "This is a quote." But this is not a valid string literal"
s = "He said: ""This is a quote."" This is  a valid string literal"
```

Normally the VBA editor will recognize such invalid string literals. But here I was confusing it with comparison operators.

For the string literal within the formula, I required double quotations. Full answer below.

Comment: Please show the code line which throws the error "Object Required". `.FormulaArray = "=SUM(SUMIFS(B!$D:$D,B!$E:$E,$A5,B!$B:$B,"">=""&E$2,B!$B:$B,""<""&F$2)*1,SUMIFS(B!$D:$D,B!$F:$F,$A5,B!$B:$B,"">=""&E$2,B!$B:$B,""<""&F$2)*-1)"` works for me.

Comment: That's exactly it, you need to use double quotes `""` if you need quotes in the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a string literal is enclosed in double quotes and we need double quotes in the string literal, then we must mask those double quotes somehow. If we don't, the unmasked double quote will end the string literal. This is the case with all programming languages.

In VBA we mask double quotes by repeating them.

```
Dim s As String
's = "He said: "This is a quote." But this is not a valid string literal"
s = "He said: ""This is a quote."" This is  a valid string literal"
```

Normally the VBA editor will recognize such invalid string literals. But here you are confusing it with comparison operators.

```
s = "Sting literal 1" >= "Sting literal 2"
```

So `s` will become the string representation of a boolean value `FALSE` since the comparison is false.

The following will work:

```
.FormulaArray = "=SUM(SUMIFS(B!$D:$D,B!$E:$E,$A5,B!$B:$B,"">=""&E$2,B!$B:$B,""<""&F$2)*1,SUMIFS(B!$D:$D,B!$F:$F,$A5,B!$B:$B,"">=""&E$2,B!$B:$B,""<""&F$2)*-1)"
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for explaining! Yes, working now. Unfortunately, this has presented a new problem for me. But that's for another question. Awesome